# Is there a gdb-show-main equivalent for gud-lldb?

Tags: debugging, emacs, lldb

I used to use Gnu Emacs for debugging on Mac using gud-gdb, and in my gdb-mode-hook I could turn on gdb-show-main to get the debugger to show execution and breakpoints directly in my source code buffer.  Now gdb is gone and I have to use lldb.  I have a gud-lldb.el installed and working, but it only shows a few source lines at a time in the interaction buffer.  Is there a way to get it working similar to how gud-gdb worked with gdb-show-main set?  I have Emacs 27.2 installed.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of a straight forward answer to this.  You might find have some luck with [realgud](https://github.com/realgud/realgud) which does have a module for lldb.  However, I found it to be pretty painful with a complex C++ project in a variety of ways, and eventually resorted to hacking out bits of the code to give me something that was "good enough" to let me get some work done.  Depending on your needs it's probably worth a try?

Comment: Thank you @stevoooo, I'm debugging plain C and it seems to be working for me so far.